# Need help with ternary operators!

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2,
        found == true ? fieldName : "", found  == true ? "product" : "");
```

Is there a way to combine the two `found == true` ternary operation into a more succinct piece of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long lines with multiple ternary operators can be really illegible. Line breaks help a *little* with readability.

```
field = string.Format(Str,
    value1,
    value2,
    found ? fieldName : "",
    found ? "product" : "");
```

Answer (score 19):

You don't need the `== true` bit:

```
field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2, found ? fieldName : "", found ? "product" : "");
```

However, in my view the following is easier to read:

```
if (found) {
    field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2, fieldName, "product");
}
else {
    field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2, "", "");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is just an opinion but...
YUK!  I hate reading code like this.

Ternary operators may make for less code, but readability is suffering here.  Don't go for less lines of code if it hurts readability.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
field = found ? string.Format(Str, value1, value2, fieldName, "product")
              : string.Format(Str, value1, value2, "", "");
```

Only one ternary, more readable than the original example, but I would consider a if/else statement for readability...

Comment: Well, that *does* give him what he asked for, but it's a bad use of the ternary operator.

Comment: +1 - That's an interesting approach that had never occurred to me before for handling these sorts of things.

Comment: Although it's somewhat a stylistic preference, I feel the ternary operator is best suited to cases where you want make *simple* assignments.  In my mind, this version reads "Assign one of two strings based on the value of *found*."  What I'm inferring about the intent of the code feels more like it should say "Assign a string, and differentiate individual parts based on the value of found."  I may be reading too much into the example, but my comment reflects my initial gut instinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can abbreviate it like so:

```
field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2, found ? fieldName : "", found ? "product" : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop comparing `found` to `true`. You want the condition on whether or not the item was `found`, not whether or not `found` is `true`:

```
found ? fieldName : string.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to true is unnecessary:

```
field = string.Format(Str, value1, value2, found ? fieldName : "", found ? "product" : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `String.Format` takes a `params` array, the one major variation not yet suggested would be

```
field = string.Format(Str, found
                      ? new object[] {value1, value2, fieldName, "product"}
                      : new object[] {value1, value2, string.Empty, string.Empty});
```

Answer (score 0):

That line of code took my manual parser a few moments longer to digest than I would like.  I'm all for succinct and elegant coding, but wouldn't you rather come across this in a few months time, albeit over a few more lines?

`if (found)

    // Use empty strings for fieldName and productName

    field = String.Format(Str, value1, value2, fieldName, productName);

else

    // Use the fieldName and productName in the string

    field = String.Format(Str, value1, value2, String.Empty, String.Empty);`

Just my personal taste, but I know which one I'd rather encounter.